# Check gmail is loggedin with an authenticate user?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am beginner in Selenium webdriver, and I have made a simple gmail login script using the Firefox IDE, now what I want to do is check that the login was successful done by authenticate user or verify that XYZ user has logged in.

Comment: What is the question?.do you have  code that does not work?

Comment: @Jack below are the code now I want to verify the user that authenticate user has been loggedIn, if so then case will be passed either fail.

public class RunWebDriver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
wd.get("https://www.gmail.com");
WebElement we = wd.findElement(By.id("Email"));
we.sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
WebElement we1 = wd.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
we1.sendKeys("2013");
WebElement we2 = wd.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
we2.click();
try { wd.wait(2000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {
}wd.close(); }}

Answer (score 0):

If it is successful log in it will redirect to another page. there write one assert statement/conditional statement for particular object (logged user name/details) available or not.

or else get the title of the page if two webpages(before redirect,after redirect) have different titles.

Comment: If we take an example for gmail login and in these we apply the same thing then how we can apply it??
It would be helpful for me if you let me know.. thanks in advance...!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the inbox button is present after clicking on the submit button.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(theWebDriverImplementation.driver, 100);

driver.findElement(By.id(".submit")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(".inbox")));
```

Comment: can you please let me know the same with username verification, above code are given.